# Validación de Session caduca mediante websocket o Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, websocket

Estoy desarrollando un sistema web y me tranqué en una parte de la validación de sesiones.

Mediante un Controller Base  y jQuery (Ajax o WebSocket), intento notificar al usuario que su session ha finalizado con un mensaje en un popup y una posterior redirección a la página de login.

Bueno eso es lo que estoy intentando hacer, aparte de eso, la sesión debe durar 3 min y las  validaciones deben ser cada 10 segundos. ¿Dónde hago la configuración del tiempo de la sesión y del tiempo de las validaciones o cómo encargo este segundo aspecto?

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera:
Action que valida la sesion:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Espera(string usuario)
    {
        Exito obj = new Exito();
        if (Session["usuario"] == null)
            obj.resul = false; 
        else
            obj.resul = true;

        return Json(obj);
    }
```

Código cliente (Vista)

```
@model XXX.Models.Exito

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Espera";
}

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

<h3>Espera...</h3>

<h2>Aqui nos mantenemos a la espera que caduque la SESSION</h2>

<h1>Usuario: @Session["usuario"]</h1>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    function myFunction() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/XXX/Espera",
            data: '{usuario: "' + "" + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.resul == false) {
                    alert("Estimado Choco, su Session ya caduco.");
                    window.location = 'http://localhost:37728/XXX/Index';
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }

    setInterval(myFunction, 10000);
});
</script>
```

Ahi se los dejo para quienes les sirva

Comment: Deberías aceptar tu respuesta haciendo click en el ✔️ que está a la izquierda, debajo de las flechas de votación.... Y esto mismo con todas las preguntas que hiciste para las cuales hayas recibido una buena respuesta